# Composition of linear functions, but backwards?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that if a composition of functions is linear, then the two functions it is composed of are also linear?

ie. $f_i(x) = g_i(T(x))$, where $f_i$ is linear. Does this imply $T$ is linear? 
For this specific question, we also have $g_i$ is linear.

Comment: A rewording might help clarify; if you intend for $g_i$ to also be linear, it would make sense to mention that earlier, before asking if the conditions imply that $T$ is linear.

Comment: No it is not always true. Take squaring and square root plus constant. $\sqrt{x^2}+C$ is linear on positive reals but neither of squaring or root + C is.

Answer (score 7):

If $f(x)=g(T(x))$, $f$ and $g$ are linear, *and $g$ is invertible*, then $T(x)=g^{-1}(f(x))$ is linear, because the inverse of a linear function is linear, and a composition of linear functions is linear.  However, if $g$ is not one-to-one, $T$ might have nonlinear behavior that gets hidden by mapping into parts of the domain of $g$ that all get mapped to the same point.  For example, if $g(x)=0$ and $T(x)=e^x$, then $g$ and $f$ are linear but $T$ isn't.

Answer (score 3):

No. The composition on *non-linear* function can be linear.

Consider the functions $\mathrm h(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $\mathrm k(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, where $x>0$.

We have $(\mathrm h \circ \mathrm k)(x) = x$ for all $x>0$:

$$(\mathrm h \circ \mathrm k)(x) = \frac{1}{1/x}\equiv x$$

This is a linear function, but neither h nor k are linear.

Comment: It's rather confusing that you're using the letters $f$ and $g$ differently from how the question uses them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see what you mean now. I've changed the letters.